# Instagram Sandbox to Live

Tags: php, instagram

I create new App in Instagram Developer today.
But because of API update,my App created in sandbox mode.

in order to remove restriction, I try to go live mode.

Official document is as follow.

> To switch your client from sandbox to live mode, you can use the
>   button on the top section of the configuration screen

https://instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

But the button isn't active! I can't push button!

So I want to know how to activate [GO LIVE] Button.

Comment: `After your app has been reviewed and approved` may be the issue. But this isn't really a programming question.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question!And I'm sorry to ask bad question.

Comment: See this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35016819/how-can-i-put-my-instagram-client-into-live-mode

Answer (score 2):

The documentation clearly states that they will be accepting new apps for review *after* Dec 03, 2015. You can't 'go live' before then.

Comment: Thank you very much!I coudn't understand document correctly.I have no choice but to wait Dec 03...

Answer (score 0):

To get out of Sandbox mode, you need to submit your app for review. If your app falls into the approved use cases and gets approved, it will automatically go live. At this point any Instagram user will be able to authorize your app, but you will have access only to the permissions that you were granted during the review. If you need access to more permissions, you can submit for review again and you will not lose access to the permissions that you have already been granted.
you can see this 
https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to submit for review for this use case. Some widgets may ask you to register a new client ID, but you should not submit it for review for the widget to work. Your client can remain in sandbox mode and the widget will have access to your last 20 media. If you are having issues with the widget, please contact the owner of the widget directly.
i m getting this..