# How can I put my Instagram client into Live mode?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I downloaded Instagram yesterday so I could sign up and then created a new client which is currently in Sandbox mode. I have created a website which searches for certain hashtags across Twitter and Instagram and the only thing which holds me back from going live is that the Instagram client is still in sandbox mode.

The "Go Live" button is disabled and I have no idea what I need to do to get it enabled. The documentation doesn't say anything. It mentions somewhere that there is a review process, but I don't even see an option to submit my application for a review. How does that even work anyway, because my application is not a phone app. I have made a website which is mobile friendly but it doesn't even require a user login.

Any more information and clarification is much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is really a programming question. It seems like it's not _directly_ related to programming, but to using Instagram -- albeit in a way that's related to development.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have get your app reviewed by Instagram first.

Click `Edit` for your client, Click on the `Permissions` tab and submit for review. Once approved, u will be able to click `Go Live`

Comment: Thank you, that was what I missed, because the Start Submission button was greyed out as well, because I did not fill out the Company name, because I don't have a company and it is a private project so it doesn't even make sense to have this as a required field.

Comment: I'm approved, but I don't see a "go live" button.  Never have.

Comment: Update: thats because my app was created before Nov. - If I create a new app it has the Go Live button.

Comment: When I start a submission, I choose "I want to display my Instagram posts on my website". 

It says: "You do not need to submit for review for this use case. If you are a developer and you want to display Instagram content on your website, then you do not need to submit your app for review. By using a client in sandbox mode, you can still access the last 20 media of any sandbox user that grants you permission."

Ok I got it. But then there is no button to switch to LIVE? =.=

Comment: you dont need to go live, you can stay in sandbox mode and you can get your latest 20 photos using API

Comment: @krisrak I want to display more than 20 photos, is any way to activate live mode to display my instagram posts on my website?

Comment: @TamilSelvanC you have to get your app approved by Instagram

Comment: @krisrak
I want to show hashtag images in my site so 
 I go to permission tab and click on register it gives me radio buttons when i click on " I want to display hashtag content and public content on my website." it is throwing error "You do not need to submit for review for this use case." Can you tell me how can i go to live

Comment: instagram does not approve API to just display on your website, also the hashtag API is deprecated

Answer (score 2):

Since 17th of November, Instagram made his API more protected for spam/fraud/copycat apps. 
You can read more about it here: https://www.instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/

Answer (score 2):

I put my application from last 12 days in Instagram Developer Console but not getting any reply from them so I found a new way to submit the app using below steps and It's work for me. 
**Old Process:-**  
[image]

I think there is some update related to the **Instagram App review**, **please check below steps** & screenshot you will get the idea of how to submit **Instagram app from Sandbox to Live mode in the new updates**. 
**Steps:-** 
1) https://developers.facebook.com/ Click on this link and enter into the facebook developer console.

2) Now click on My App or Create the new app if there is not any created.

3) Click on Product(+) which is in the left side panel (More clarification see the attached screenshot)

4) Select the Instagram and click on Add button

5) Now you will be able to see one more menu in panel namely "Instagram" (More clarification see the attached screenshot)
[image] 
6) Click on that and you will be able to see the list of permission in right side view
[image]
7) Select your respective permission which you require and submit the app for review.

**[Note:- You need to give your .apk and .zip file accordingly android & iOS. You also need to submit screencast of your flow and especially to show the part which indicates why you need this permission]**

Comment: Tried this and it seems that now is also required to request manage_pages for some reason. Did you had to request that permission too?

Comment: Yes, I also provided to them.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way for live mode after Instagram Platform Updated on June, 2016.

1) Manage Clients -> MANAGE -> Sandbox(Tab) -> Add user name to Sandbox User and Save.

2) Open the Permissions Tab and click Start a submission button to put your client into live mode.

Comment: what we need to select in permission tab ?

Answer (score 0):

1) Manage Clients -> MANAGE -> Sandbox(Tab) -> Add user name to Sandbox User and Save.

2) Open the Permissions Tab and click Start a submission button to put your client into live mode.

After this process take how much time for live the instagarm